# Query citext column from schema using npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to use a citext column in a simple WHERE clause from a table in a non-public schema using npgsql 6.0.5. My (simplified) database setup is

```
create schema citest;
create table citest.testtable (
  id serial primary key,
  name public.citext
);
set search_path = citest,public;
insert into testtable (name) values ('test');
```

Running the following C# code in a .NET6 console app only finds "test" but not "Test" (upper case T)

```
class Program {

    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        string connectionString = "Server=myserver;Port=5432;Username=user;Password=pass;Database=mydatabase;Search Path=citest,public;SSLMode=Require;Trust Server Certificate=true;";
        await SelectQueryTest(connectionString, "test");
        await SelectQueryTest(connectionString, "Test");

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
    }

    private static readonly string SelectQuery =
        "select name from testtable where name = $1;";

    static async Task SelectQueryTest(string connString, string text) {
        await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);
        await connection.OpenAsync();

        await using var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(SelectQuery, connection) {
            Parameters =
            {
                new() { Value = text }
            }
        };
        await using var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        if (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
            var reply = reader.GetFieldValue<string>(0);
            Console.WriteLine($"postgres query {text}: read {reply}");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine($"postgres query {text}: read none");
        }
    }

}
```

Doing the same query using psql gives the expected result.

```
set search_path = citest,public;
select name from testtable where name = 'Test';
 name
------
 test
(1 row)
```

I would appreciate any hints that point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Npgsql explicitly types the parameters it sends, and when you send a string, Npgsql infers the `text` type. So the above is similar to writing:

```sql
select name from testtable where name = $1::text
```

... which wouldn't do a case-insensitive match (both sides need to be citext).

To fix this, explicitly specify the parameter type by setting NpgsqlDbType to Citext.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Setting NpgsqlDbType to Citext fixed the issue.
As my expectation would be that Npgsql uses the type of the database column as default can you please explain why it uses 'text' in this case?

Comment: Npgsql has no idea about yuor database column or its type - you're just asking it to send a string parameter to PostgreSQL. It doesn't parse your SQL to understand what you're going to be comparing to...